# Where should i exit in this recursive function

Tags: javascript, node.js

My goal is to write an recursive function that returns the all the files and folders inside a folder (specified by `p` in the following function) and store them in a global object in following format

```js
let filesystem = {
     file = {
              is_file : true,
              created_on : ;
              size : ;
            },
    folder = {
            is_file : true,
            created_on : ;
            size : ;
            childs : {} // This is the object to store all the content
      }
}
```

I tried doing following —

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

let globalObject = {};

function recursiveReading(p, currentObject = {}) {
    let contents = [];
    fs.readdir(p, (err, dir) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Something is wrong in Opening Folder")
            process.exit(1);
        } else {
            contents = dir;
            if (contents.length > 0) {
                contents.forEach((val) => {
                    currentObject[val] = {};
                    fs.stat(path.join(p, val), (err, stats) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error("Something is wrong in reading stat");
                            process.exit(1);
                        } else {
                            if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                                currentObject[val].isFile = false;
                                currentObject[val].createdOn = stats.ctime;
                                currentObject[val].size = stats.size;
                                currentObject[val].childs = {};
                                return recursiveReading(path.join(p, val), currentObject[val].childs);
                            } else if (stats.isFile()) {
                                currentObject[val].isFile = true;
                                currentObject[val].createdOn = stats.ctime;
                                currentObject[val].size = stats.size;
                            }
                            globalThis.globalObject = currentObject;
                        }
                    })
                })
            } else {
                return currentObject;
            }
        }

    })
}


recursiveReading(__dirname, globalObject);

console.log(globalObject);
```

But i'm stuck now, what should be my exit from this recursive function, and how can i return the value of `currentObject`.

Thank u.

Comment: Typically, when you don't find directly it should stop calling the recursion. You don't have to exit as such

Comment: 1. You have finite directories and won't get into infinite loop. 2. You cannot return `currentObject` directly since the function is asynchronous. Use callback or promise.

Comment: or, you can use fs.readdirsync, fs.statsync, etc. (sync versions) to execute synchronously. Then you can return the object directly. However, my recommendation would be to use promises.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to return the result directly, you can avoid the second parameter.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const fsp = require('fs/promises');
const path = require('path');

async function recursiveReading(p) {
  const curObj = {}
  const stat = await fsp.stat(p);
  
  curObj[p] = {
    isFile: stat.isFile(),
    createdOn: stat.ctime,
    size: stat.size,
  }
  if(stat.isDirectory()) {
    const contents = await fsp.readdir(p);
    curObj[p].childs = {}
    for(let content of contents) {
      curObj[p].childs = {
        ...curObj[p].childs,
        [path.join(p,content)]: await recursiveReading(path.join(p, content)),
      };
    }
  }
  return curObj;
}


function recursiveReadingSync(p) {
  const curObj = {}
  const stat = fs.statSync(p);
  
  curObj[p] = {
    isFile: stat.isFile(),
    createdOn: stat.ctime,
    size: stat.size,
  }
  if(stat.isDirectory()) {
    const contents = fs.readdirSync(p);
    curObj[p].childs = {}
    for(let content of contents) {
      curObj[p].childs = {
        ...curObj[p].childs,
        [path.join(p,content)]: recursiveReading(path.join(p, content)),
      };
    }
  }
  return curObj;
}

recursiveReading('.').then(data => console.log('async', data))

console.log('sync', recursiveReadingSync('.'))
```

Some points to note:

1. You cannot return directly from an asynchronous function( the one which uses callbacks or promises internally). You have to either return a Promise or execute a callback.
2. Hence, if you want to return directly, prefer using a synchronous version.
3. It is better to avoid grammatically wrong words like `childs`. Prefer `children`